# Porque se é banido na versão inglês do Stack Overflow?

Tags: suporte

Já há algum tempo fui banido do Stack Overflow na versão inglês. Acredito que na época não entendia em as politicas do site. Só recentemente fui aprender a marcar as questões como resolvidas, antes achava que tinha que editar o título, para se ter uma ideia.

Por lá já arrumei tudo, inclusive aumentei minha classificação, mas continuo banido de fazer perguntas.

Como posso voltar a participar da versão em Inglês?

Comment: Complicado, cada stack é independente entre si, quem vai poder te responder isso é somente os moderadores de la. Mas se você acha que foi banido injustamente, pode entrar em contato com a staff por este link: http://stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: Acabei de ver seu perfil la, e não está banido. O que te levou a crer que você foi banido?

Comment: Eu já fui "banido" por excluir uma pergunta com mais de 1 resposta. Este é um de outros vários motivos que pode te inibir de fazer outras perguntas no SOen.

Comment: @diegofm Que não permite que eu faça novas perguntas... mas hoje que fui qualificar as que tinha feito por lá.

Comment: @acklay pode ser isso...

Comment: Tem como você apresentar a mensagem que aparece quando você tenta criar uma pergunta? Assim talvez facilite alguém dizer a razão.

Comment: @diegofm A mensagem é: You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: Banimento só pode ser revertido se a pessoa melhorar seus posts, ele próprio reverter a situação criada. Como eu não tenho acesso a tudo lá, não posso ver o que foi removido não tenho como opinar. Aceitar respostas não muda nada. O que bane alguém é ter muitos posts considerados ruins, em geral negativos. E remover só piora a situação. Tem que consertá-los. Esse é um erro muito comum que as pessoas cometem. Elas acham que se ficar ruim pro lado dela é só remover que está livre e é o oposto, a remoção é a confissão que fez coisa errada e não vai consertar. Não sei detalhes sobre isso.

Comment: Isso acontece quando uma serie de publicações (perguntas/respostas) são bastantes negativadas, perguntas fechadas em um curto período. A mensagem informando o motivo deve indicar esse link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: Obrigado @rray, vou tentar me recuperar por lá.

Comment: @Ramos lembrando que usualmente nada disto é permanente, é apenas um limitador de tempo. O que significa que precisa aguardar um pouco, mas é liberado para postar depois de um tempo. É uma maneira do sistema fazer com que a pessoa "vá com calma" para elaborar melhor as postagens, e resolver o problema. O site em inglês e o em português tem algumas políticas diferentes, mas [ask] e [help] podem ser úteis como referência.

Comment: Deixa de aceitar respostas não é motivo para banimento e até aonde sei não existe banimento, mas sim "penalidade" (cantinho da disciplina), vc é bloqueado por um tempo pré-determinado. Basta esperar que logo irá voltar, agora se vc não esta penalizado mas sim bloqueado de criar novas perguntas, então o teu problema é que vc deve ter deletado suas proprias perguntas ou respostas e não fez mais participações relevantes. Uma maneira de melhorar isto é responder novas perguntas ou restaurar uma resposta tua deletada e tentar melhora-la.

Comment: Vide ---> [**What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/1287812)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Por lá já arrumei tudo, inclusive aumentei minha classificação, mas continuo banido de fazer perguntas.

Não existe banimento até aonde eu sei, o que existe é penalidade, só ocorre em alguns casos extremos, como:

- Fraudes
- SPAM
- Ataques e ofensas que você tenha cometido

No entanto nenhum destes é o seu caso, ou seja você não está nem banido e nem penalizado, na verdade você deve estar **"vetado"**, veja este link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans, no SOen você deve ter recebido uma mensagem como esta:

> We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See [**the Help Center**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) to learn more.

Isto é um "veto" (ou bloqueio automático de uma ação especifica), o veto não lhe impede de atuar em geral, apenas em uma atividade especifica, no seu caso creio que você esteja impedido de "perguntar" e talvez de "responder", veja como sair do veto:

> O único jeito de encerrar um bloqueio de publicação é contribuir positivamente com o site; os vetos automáticos nunca expiram nem "excedem o tempo limite". **Comece corrigindo suas publicações existentes**; não publique simplesmente a mesma pergunta novamente. Todas as perguntas devem ser úteis também para futuros visitantes, portanto escreva com gramática e ortografia corretas, formatando sua publicação de modo que possa ser lida facilmente e fornecendo todos os detalhes possíveis sobre seu problema e o que você já tentou. A leitura da sua pergunta em voz alta para si mesmo pode ajudar a entender como ela soa para os outros.

Ou seja, uma maneira de melhorar isto é responder novas perguntas ou restaurar uma pergunta/resposta tua deletada e tentar melhora-la, depende muito do que você fez anteriormente.

---

### Observação

Se você estiver bloqueado no SOpt então a mensagem deve ser algo como:

> Não aceitamos mais perguntas desta conta. Consulte [a Central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) para saber mais.