# Existe penalidade ao remover minhas respostas?

Tags: suporte, respostas

Respondi uma pergunta mas minha resposta esta sendo negativada,e mesmo editando ela continua sendo negativada. Existe alguma penalidade por apagar respostas? Assim sendo, melhor manter a resposta na pergunta ou posso apagar minhas respostas com qualidade aparentemente ruim?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Porque se é banido na versão inglês do Stack Overflow?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5944/porque-se-%c3%a9-banido-na-vers%c3%a3o-ingl%c3%aas-do-stack-overflow) - você deve estar falando do "veto", não é uma *penalidade*, é um veto apenas, para meio que te direcionar para um caminho melhor, leia o link passei.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apagar respostas normalmente não gera penalidade. No entanto:

- Se a resposta estiver aceita, apenas moderadores podem apagar.
- Se for considerado que conteúdo importante de alta qualidade foi removido injustamente pelo autor, os moderadores podem restaurá-lo. Entretanto, casos disso são bem raros e excepcionais.

Ou seja, apagar uma resposta sua que recebeu votos negativos não tem problema.

Quanto a apagar perguntas, você não pode em alguns casos:

- Quando a pergunta tem ao menos uma resposta com votação positiva.
- Quando a pergunta tem resposta aceita.
- Quando a pergunta tem duas ou mais respostas.

Mais detalhes [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/176034).

Apagar suas próprias perguntas ou respostas com votação >= +3 te dá a medalha de bronze [disciplinado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined). Apagar suas próprias perguntas ou respostas com votação <= -3, te dá a medalha de bronze [pressão dos colegas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure). Entretanto, você só pode adquirir essas medalhas uma vez.

Apagar perguntas ou respostas suas em massa vai sinalizar os moderadores que algo está errado e eles podem suspender a sua conta por um dia ou uma semana para você se acalmar, esfriar a cabeça e conversar com eles sobre o que está errado. Isso também é útil no caso de alguém roubar a sua senha e começar a vandalizar as suas perguntas e respostas, os moderadores vão interromper a atividade assim que a perceberem.

Comment: A resposta abaixo é mais correcta, ainda que muito do que aqui foi dito seja correcto: apagar posts _pode_ contribuir para o utilizador ficar bloqueado. cc @Arcashaid

Answer (score 18):

Sim e não.

Se você apagar uma publicação negativada, você pode recuperar a reputação que perdeu pelos votos negativos. Eu digo *"pode"*, porque se a publicação for antiga, a reputação não será revertida.

No entanto... Isso pode não funcionar a seu favor. Se você tiver muitas publicações negativadas o sistema pode bloquear sua conta temporariamente e você será incapaz de perguntar ou responder. Quando mais votos negativos, maior o tempo de bloqueio. Agora a surpresa para os novatos: **publicações deletadas também contam para a decisão e o tempo desse bloqueio.** Por isso, é sempre do seu melhor interesse melhorar as suas publicações ao invés de apagá-las.

Sobre as regras de bloqueio: a equipe de desenvolvimento do Stack Overflow não as divulga, para que elas não possam ser abusadas. Mais um motivo pelo qual é de seu interesse melhorar publicações ao invés de apagá-las.

E se em qualquer momento você achar que leva votos negativos demais, lembre-se sempre de duas coisas:

- Todo mundo leva voto negativo. Até os usuários com mais pontos ainda levam negativos de vez em quando. Faz parte do aprendizado. Os votos negativos servem para que avaliemos melhor o formato de nossas publicações, e se são apropriadas para o site. Se você seguir o exemplo de publicações bem-avaliadas, logo logo você cresce na rede;
- E o principal: não leve a sua reputação a sério demais. É só um número. Existem pessoas que dão excelentes respostas, ou que fazem excelentes perguntas, que têm pouca reputação porque não participam muito. E aqui e acolá tem gente como eu - nunca programei uma linha de PHP na vida mas estou muito perto de ganhar uma medalha na tag dessa linguagem.

Comment: Esta é a resposta mais correta.

Comment: Sim; ver [este post no MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/208518) para mais detalhes sobre o bloqueio.