# Editar ou perguntar novamente?

Tags: debate

Recentemente vi orientações para que a pergunta não fosse repetida e sim editada, não seria melhor a recomendação de excluir a anterior e perguntar novamente?

Comment: Se é possivel editar, por que criar novamente?

Comment: @Articuno É só uma duvida, não teria mais chances de ser respondida? também para um usuário leigo editar não faz muito sentido.

Comment: Minha pergunta foi retórica.

Comment: @FelipeDuarte- *Não teria mais chances de ser respondida?* - Não! Pelo contrário, a chance é que você seja considerado um usuário "vândalo" no site. Ninguém que usa o site para responder quer ver a mesma pergunta sendo criada várias vezes só porque na primeira vez ela não teve a recepção que o OP achou que ela deveria ter.

Comment: @EMBarbosa, ta certíssimo!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se fizer isto poderá sofrer penalidades automáticas pelo sistema. Perguntas devem ser sempre boas. Se fez uma ruim, **edite, corrija**, não abandone. Se for incentivado abandonar ficaremos com um monte de zumbi.

Que vantagem há em apagar? Ter uma pergunta novinha em folha sem o vício já criado é mais uma desvantagem para a comunidade do que vantagem. O sistema em geral pensa primeiro na comunidade.

Se permitir que a pessoa apague porque recebeu negativos é um incentivo para ela fazer perguntas ruins. Se a pessoa apagar porque quer se livrar dos negativos ela precisa de uma punição para evitar o abuso disto.

Há uma [resposta que fala exatamente isto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6425/101) (note que a resposta aceita está errada).

Comment: Legal, mas não consegui entender ainda a desvantagem para a comunidade, me refiro a perguntas boas como essa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247188/comunica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-arduino-pythosqlserver-codigo

Comment: Incentivar as pessoas fazerem perguntas ruins e abandonar lá não prejudica a comunidade? Ficar tendo duplicatas com o mesmo conteúdo não poluí? Não gera ruído para a comunidade ter que lidar? O sistema é pensado para a pessoa ter bom comportamento, então se ela errou, conserte, não deve largar lixo pelo caminho. Sujou o prato, limpa, não vai pegar outro.

Comment: Minha pergunta foi 'eu sujo meu prato, lavo e guardo, e depois pego um novo, caso o anterior não esteja quebrado'.

Comment: Só que sujou e pegou outro, o ideal era não ter sujado. Se deixar as pessoas vão sujar, ela vão sujar e cria uma dificuldade para a comunidade lidar. Se tiver uma punição as pessoas evitarão sujar e se não tiver jeito e sujar ela é incentivada a ficar com seu prato.

Comment: Você viu a pergunta, a qual editei e manti as informações originais? (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/246276/66203) @FelipeDuarte. Pelo que entendo de comunidade Q&A, acho que editar a pergunta e não duplicá-la é a abordagem correta. Nesse comentário (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/246276/como-gravar-os-dados-que-s%C3%A3o-captados-do-sensor-dht22#comment506682_246276), já dava para entender que teríamos que **editar, corrigir**, e não abandonar. Eu não tenho experiência com Arduino, mas me parece uma boa pergunta, só tem que "aparar as pontas" para o escopo de um Q&A.

Comment: @Stormwind, vi sim,entendo perfeitamente, mas não estou entendendo o que está acontecendo com a galera aqui, minha pergunta não tem nada a ver com, duplicar pergunta, abandonar pergunta ou gerar ruído, falo de EXCLUIR a pergunta anterior, e pergunta-la novamente, atingindo assim a seção de perguntas recentes, onde tem muito mais chances de serem respondidas, simples assim.

Comment: Mas não é necessário excluir @FelipeDuarte, basta editar que já é gerado um *bump* na página inicial. Se essa foi sua preocupação, ela não vai ficar abandonada, basta editar e não excluir e perguntar novamente.